# command not found even though directory is in $PATH

Tags: ubuntu, bash, path

I'm having trouble running a program which should be on my $path, but apparently isn't. When I run it with the full path, it works fine, but when I only call the executable, it says command not found. This is despite the directory being on my path. Permissions are fine as far as I can see, and I have tried moving it into several different locations without luck.
Here is a snapshot of the issue, minizinc is the executable in question.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/minzinc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$ minizinc
minizinc: command not found
$ /usr/local/minizinc/bin/minizinc 
minizinc: no model file specified
minizinc: use --help for more information.
$ ls -l /usr/local/minizinc/bin/minizinc 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2747036 2012-10-20 12:51 /usr/local/minizinc/bin/minizinc
```

I'm running ubutnu 11.04, and using bash as my shell.

Comment: What do you get if you execute: `type minizinc`?  Could a `minizinc` executable be in `/usr/local/heroku/bin` that is for a different platform is missing a required shared library?  I only ask that because I was burnt by this myself.

Comment: `$ type minizinc` just gives  `bash: type: minizinc: not found`. There is no conflicting file in `/usr/local/heroku/bin` unfortunately :(

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Andrew! Since your problem just stemmed from a typo, I've closed this question as being too localized now – it's unlikely someone else will run into the exact same issue. Glad you got the problem figured out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/minzinc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

You appear to be missing an `i` in `minizinc` in `/usr/local/minzinc/bin`.

Comment: Not at all.  It happens to everyone.